# How to compute AVG over the set of first records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

Logs:

```
id   |  record_id  | event_type  | user  |
==========================================
1    |  1          |  A          |  X    |
2    |  1          |  B          |  X    |
3    |  1          |  A          |  X    |
4    |  2          |  A          |  X    |
5    |  2          |  A          |  X    |
6    |  2          |  A          |  X    |
```

Records:

```
record_id  |  score  |
======================
1          |    9    |
2          |    3    |
```

I would like to compute the **AVG for all the rows from Records which are mentioned in the record_id in Logs, for the event_type 'A', for each user**.

In this example - user X should be assigned the AVG score of:
    9+3/2 = 6, since both record 1 & 2 are mentioned in the Logs table for user X & event_type 'A'.

My problem is that each record_id can appear more than once for each combination of user & event_type in Logs, and it should be considered in the AVG only once.

So for the upper example: user X has 2 Logs rows with the event type of 'A' which refer to record 1, and 3 Logs rows with the event type of 'A' which refer to record 2, but the AVG should be computed only from the first row in Logs of user X & event_type 'A' & record 1.

Any ideas about how to compute the AVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the distinct `Logs` records in a subquery before joining with `Records` and averaging.

```
SELECT user, AVG(score) AS avg_score
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, record_id
      FROM Logs) AS l
JOIN Records AS r ON l.record_id = r.record_id
GROUP BY user
```